# Lua: string.rep nested inside string.gsub?

Tags: string, lua, gsub, repeat

I would like to be able to take a string and repeat every substring following a number that amount of times while removing the number. For example "5 north, 3 west" --> "north north north north north, west west west". This is what I tried:

```
test = "5 north, 3 west"
test = test:gsub("(%d) (%w+)", string.rep("%2 ", tonumber("%1")) )
Note(test)
```

But I just get an error like "number expected got Nil."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a function as the second parameter to `gsub`:

```
test = "5 north, 3 west"
test = test:gsub("(%d) (%w+)",
  function(s1, s2) return string.rep(s2.." ", tonumber(s1)) end)
print(test)
```

This prints `north north north north north , west west west`.

Comment: Guess I don't even need to use tonumber(). Or should I use it anyways?

Comment: It works without tonumber for me in Lua 5.1, but it doesn't hurt to have it.

Answer (score 3):

To improve a bit on Kulchenko's answer:

```
test = "5 north, 3 west"
test = test:gsub("(%d+) (%w+)",
  function(s1, s2) return s2:rep(tonumber(s1),' ') end)
print(test)
```

Improvements:

- No space before comma
- allows for numbers over 9 (%d+) instead of (%d)